# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException PasswordResponse

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have trouble finding out what I do wrong.

This is my XML i work with

```
<PasswordResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="PasswordResponse">
<date>
<day>1</day>
<month>1</month>
<year>1</year>
</date>
<type>1</type>
<version>1</version>
<error>0</error>
<status>200</status>
<password>00000</password>
</PasswordResponse>
```

This is my Java Class

```
package testhttprequest;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class TestHttpRequest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
                    try
        {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PasswordResponse.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            PasswordResponse pr = (PasswordResponse) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(*legit-xml-input*);
            System.out.println(pr);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this here is my Java Object Class

```
package testhttprequest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="PasswordResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PasswordResponse
{
    public date date;
    public int type;
    public int version;
    public int error;
    public int status;
    public String password;

    public PasswordResponse()
    {
        this.date = new date();
        this.type = 0;
        this.version = 0;
        this.error = 0;
        this.status = 0;
    }

    public PasswordResponse(int day, int month, int year, int type, int version)
    {
        this.date = new date(day, month, year);
        this.type = type;
        this.version = version;
        this.error = 0;
        this.status = 200;

    }

    public testhttprequest.date getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public int getError()
    {
        return error;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public int getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public int getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public int getVersion()
    {
        return version;
    }

    public void setDate(testhttprequest.date date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setError(int error)
    {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setType(int type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version)
    {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

The error I get is as fallows

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"PasswordResponse", local:"PasswordResponse"). Expected elements are <{}PasswordResponse>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:648)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1051)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:484)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at testhttprequest.TestHttpRequest.sendPost(TestHttpRequest.java:78)
    at testhttprequest.TestHttpRequest.main(TestHttpRequest.java:29)
```

in the error all 3 Parameters are the same and that schould be that way, right?